# React controlled component error in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with forms in React, using function components for the first time. Either I am going crazy, or this should work with no issues...

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function ChangePasswordComponent(props) {

  const {onChangePassword} = props;
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    password: undefined,
    confirm: undefined
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    handleValidation();
  }, [form])

  function handleValidation() {
    setIsValid(form.password === form.confirm);
  }

  function onFormValueChanges(event) {
    setForm({...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  function resetFields() {
    setForm({
      password: undefined,
      confirm: undefined
    })
  }

  function onUpdateClick() {
    onChangePassword(form.password);
    resetFields();
  }

  return (
    <div className="change-password-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="password"
        value={form.password}
        onChange={(event) => onFormValueChanges(event)}
        placeholder="new password" />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="confirm"
        value={form.confirm}
        onChange={(event) => onFormValueChanges(event)}
        placeholder="confirm new password" />
      {!isValid ? 
        <span className="validation-error">passwords do not match</span> : null }
      <div className="button-container">
        <button onClick={() => resetFields()}>Cancel</button>
        <button onClick={() => onUpdateClick()}
          disabled={!form.password || !isValid}>Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default ChangePasswordComponent;
```

However when I run the code I get an error in console about...

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

When I look back into the documentation, my pattern seems to follow the Docs just fine. Thoughts?

Comment: you should use **empty string** like `''` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Also, not part of the problem, but wanted to point out you have useEffect in your code twice calling the same function.

Comment: thanks @DragonWhite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use empty strings like '' instead of undefined.

when your component has first rendered, password and confirm values are `undefined`. This means that there is no variable to set the `value` attribute of the input.
Therefore, that error occurs.